# how to convert a String to Binary code for Build a File?

Tags: .net, vb.net, binary, arrays

well in a database is saved a binary code (this is a *.jar)
i need to download this code (with  a select query) and Rebuild this file

What are the setps for convert since a String to a File?

someone told me i need convert it to  array byte, but i dont know how to convert a String to a array byte... what are the best steps?

this code return me a table

```
Public Function ConseguirCatalogo() As DataTable


        Return conn.RegresarTabla("select archivo from catalogo where id= (select id from periodos where actual=1)")

    End Function
```

and this code i get the String

Private Sub EnviarArchivo() 'para el catalogo

```
Dim MyTable As DataTable = consultas.ConseguirCatalogo()
Dim binarycode As String = MyTable.Rows(0)(0).ToString()
```

End Sub

now what are the next setp for convert it finally to a file? ( it is a *.jar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have converted the data into a string, it's already ruined. You should get the data as a byte array directly:

```
Dim binarycode As Byte() = DirectCast(MyTable.Rows(0)(0), Byte())
```

Comment: and now i have BinaryCode as Byte how do i convert it to a file? @Guffa

Comment: I get a bug doing it "Dim binarycode As Byte() = DirectCast(MyTable.Rows(0)(0), Byte())"... String can't convert to '1-matriz' dimensional byte @Guffa

Comment: Then it's not really binary in the database, or your `RegresarTabla` doesn't read it correctly into the data table.

Comment: no, bug is a String can't convert to a byte array its a sintaxis error